# Wordpress - form to capture the values for the custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a new entity named "ideas" having different fields. I want to add this to the admin side, where a logged in user can add/edit new "idea", which can be published/unpublished to the site.

I don't want to edit via php and make things complicated, instead do it from the wp-admin log in front-end. Is there a plugin for this? I need 3-4 such entities to be created, and define fields for each such entity.

New edit:

Custom Post Type is the best option I feel. Can anyone suggest, a free plugin for form to capture the values for the custom post type?

Comment: You are talking about **Custom Post Type**?

Comment: But can we define our own fields in that case? I mean every post would have common fields, but in my case I need different set of fields captured via form for instance.

Comment: **own fields** in wordpress is `meta box`, yes you can add as many as you can. But you have to use **PHP**

Comment: No plugin to define them?

Comment: You can use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin...but you'll still have to use PHP to make them appear in your frontend templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of two plugins to fit your needs:

1. The *Custom Post Type UI* (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) makes it possible to generate Custom Post Types (like "Posts" or "Pages") and Custom Taxonomies. This is how you can create your entity "ideas" which will show up in the admin menu.
2. With Advanced Custom Fields (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) you can define additional content fields for your "ideas"-posttype and others. It also can handle relations between your added custom-post-types

Using the SWIFT Templates as proposed in Touqueer Shafis answer will be sufficient when you only have smaller bits of information to display on the page or if you just want to display archives of your custom-post-types. But you will quickly reach the borders of these templates when it comes to single-pages.

I recommend altering the PHP of your template files manually: you will have more control where and when to display the contents of the custom-post-types and custom-fields you added on your page.

Comment: I did not get a free plugin to capture the custom post type using a form. I'll put my hands into the code.

Comment: You might want to generate your custom post types manually one day: [generatewp](http://generatewp.com) is a good starting point with helpfull features. I find working with the Advanced Custom Fields very comfortable and use them in almost every WP project I do. The [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) shows very usefull examples how to use it. Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [WCK - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Creator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/) plugin you can achieve this.

> WordPress Creation Kit consists of three tools that can help you
>   create and maintain custom post types, custom taxonomies and most
>   importantly, custom fields and metaboxes for your posts, pages or
>   CPT's.
>
> WCK Custom Fields Creator offers an UI for setting up custom meta
>   boxes with custom fields for your posts, pages or custom post types.
>   Uses standard custom fields to store data.
>
> WCK Custom Post Type Creator facilitates creating custom post types by
>   providing an UI for most of the arguments of register_post_type()
>   function.
>
> WCK Taxonomy Creator allows you to easily create and edit custom
>   taxonomies for WordPress without any programming knowledge. It
>   provides an UI for most of the arguments of register_taxonomy()
>   function.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Very helpful video tutorial on the plugin page. But can I know whether it supports relationship like in http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: According to it's pro version, Swift Templates - Build your front-end templates directly from the WordPress admin UI, without writing any PHP code. Easily display registered custom post types, custom fields and taxonomies in your current theme.
Front-end Posting - form builder for content creation and editing etc.

Comment: Not that...relationship types..does it support that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not really gonna give you the answer you want to hear but I want to give you an advice from my own experience.

Using a plugin will make things usually much more complicated than doing it manually. Consider some things:

1) The plugin may not be supported for ever (or long), so if the author decides that he or she wants to be a gardener instead of a developer you're screwed. Unless you want to wrap your head around the plugin code and proceed developing it on your own. This is especially true for "underground"-plugins which are not so popular and/or maintained by a single person. Although I think you CAN rely on the "big" players like "Advanced custom fields"

2) At some point you may find that the plugin you are using doesn't support some sort of customization that you really need and quite a few plugins are built in a way that makes it hard to extend them or break out from the way they work.

So I recommend you to wrap your head around custom taxonomies and post types and just add them with PHP in your functions.php or a custom plugin. It's very very easy (it's really just arrays with arguments). You could use this visual code generator as a starting point:
http://generatewp.com/post-type/

And for adding custom fields I recommend using [Advanced custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com). You won't need any other plugin for backend management customization and it's built in a way that you can even export your custom fields as php so if they ever drop support you still have a good starting point.